# Terraform import not working for GCP crypto keys

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, hcl, google-cloud-kms

I created some crypto-keys manually and now wanted to import them to terraform state so that it's managed by terraform, which I did using following command which completes successfully:

```
$ terraform import google_kms_crypto_key.some-key some-gcp-project-id/us/some-keyring/some-key
google_kms_crypto_key.some-key: Refreshing state... [id=projects/some-gcp-project-id/locations/us/keyRings/some-keyring/cryptoKeys/some-key]

Import successful!

The resources that were imported are shown above. These resources are now in
your Terraform state and will henceforth be managed by Terraform.
```

Even after the import, on doing `terraform apply` I am still getting resource already exists error:

```
Error: Error creating CryptoKey: googleapi: Error 409: CryptoKey projects/some-gcp-project-id/locations/us/keyRings/some-keyring/cryptoKeys/some-key already exists.
```

Since this resource has been imported, I believe I shouldn't be getting this "Error 409". In `terrform plan` steps, it first destroys the existing key contents and then tries to re-create the key - which leads to error since the key already exists. Since I have already imported the key I do not want terraform to destroy the key. Why is terraform trying to destroy a key which has already been imported?

This is the relevant part of `terrform` plan output

```
# google_kms_crypto_key.some-key[1] will be destroyed
  - resource "google_kms_crypto_key" "some-key" {
      - destroy_scheduled_duration    = "86400s" -> null
      - id                            = "projects/some-gcp-project-id/locations/us/keyRings/some-keyring/cryptoKeys/some-key" -> null
      - import_only                   = false -> null
      - key_ring                      = "projects/some-gcp-project-id/locations/us/keyRings/some-keyring" -> null
      - labels                        = {} -> null
      - name                          = "some-key" -> null
      - purpose                       = "ENCRYPT_DECRYPT" -> null
      - rotation_period               = "2592000s" -> null
      - skip_initial_version_creation = false -> null

      - timeouts {}

      - version_template {
          - algorithm        = "GOOGLE_SYMMETRIC_ENCRYPTION" -> null
          - protection_level = "SOFTWARE" -> null
        }
    }

  # google_kms_crypto_key.some-key["some-key"] will be created
  + resource "google_kms_crypto_key" "some-key" {
      + destroy_scheduled_duration = (known after apply)
      + id                         = (known after apply)
      + import_only                = (known after apply)
      + key_ring                   = "projects/some-gcp-project-id/locations/us/keyRings/some-keyring"
      + name                       = "some-key"
      + purpose                    = "ENCRYPT_DECRYPT"
      + rotation_period            = "2592000s"

      + version_template {
          + algorithm        = (known after apply)
          + protection_level = (known after apply)
        }
    }
```

Comment: We need to see the plan output.

Comment: I figured it out. I was using for_each to generate multiple keys; the parameter `name = each.value`. The problem was that the key_id was printed as `known after apply`. Because of this terraform cannot determine whether the key exists or not (since it cannot compute key_id before apply). So terraform tries to destroy the key-contents first, and then re-create the key which leads to error.

Any way to get around this? To resolve this I think we would need `each.value` to be computed before apply (we don't want `known after apply`).

Comment: Also updated the plan output